# Need a way to create a switch case in apex emulating the java one without break

Tags: apex, case, switch

What I'm trying to accomplish is a switch case that in Java would result in a "cascade" behavior:

```
switch(var) {
    case 'test':
        Log.d("inside test");
        // break;
    case 'test2':
        Log.d("we are going to print this as well since there is no break statement in the above case");
        break;
    default:
        Log.d("not going to print this"); 
}
```

How can I accomplish the same in Apex?
What i tried is:

```
String test = 'first';

switch on test{
    when 'first' {
        System.debug('inside first');
    }
    when 'lol' {
        System.debug('this will not be printed despite the absence of a break statement in the above case');
    }
}
```

Any idea of how to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiple switch statements, one for each group of cases is the answer in Apex. Switch fall- through is an anti-pattern for most use cases, thus leaving this answer as a comment/non-answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Apex is suited to do what you're trying to do (and the Apex `switch` definitely cannot do this).

The closest I think you'd be able to get is to use a series of independent `if` statements. Something like...

```java
Boolean cascade = false;
String month = 'September';

if(cascade || month == 'January'){
    system.debug('Jan');
    // setting cascade to true is like omitting the break in java
    cascade = true;
}

if(cascade || month == 'February'){
    system.debug('Feb');
    // setting cascade to false is like including the break in java
    cascade = false;
}

// The main difference is that a "break" here doesn't stop the other
//   "when" expressions from being evaluated.
// At least by putting the cascade check first, we can short-circuit and avoid
//   _some_ evaluation
if(cascade || month == 'March'){
    system.debug('Mar');
    cascade = true;
}

if(cascade || month == 'April'){
    system.debug('Apr');
    cascade = true;
}

if(cascade || month == 'May'){
    system.debug('May');
    cascade = true;
}

// ...and so on
```

It's a verbose mess, which is a sign that you should probably look for another approach to do whatever it is you're trying to do.